# Sens de « banalisation »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

J'ai souvent entendu l'expression  « banalisation des cours » dans le sens d'annulation. Pour moi, le mot  « banalisation » signifie  « rendre banal ». Quelqu'un peut-il m'expliquer son sens dans ce contexte-là ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il s'agit de jargon spécifique à l'Éducation nationale.

Une journée banalisée est une journée où les enseignants doivent être présents pour participer à d'autres activités que l'enseignement prévu. En conséquence, les cours banalisés sont bien des cours supprimés.

Je suppose que banaliser signifie ici qu'il n'y a plus de différence entre les activités des enseignants par rapport aux journées habituelles (maths, français, physique, géographie, etc.), les activités sont donc *banalisées*, rendues *normales*, *indifférenciées*.

Answer (score 0):

The use in education is probably a bit “official linguo” as the other person says. Maybe it helps to see how it applies generally:

Banalisation has grown a bit different from “le fait de rendre banal”, which it actually means
(Banal: dull, ordinary, common place): we use banalisation for describing something that was a rare, one off or shocking occurence and doesn’t shock or surprise anyone anymore: example “la banalisation du discours xénophobe”: xenophobic views making it to the mainstream, roughly. “La banalisation des hypermarchés”: giant supermarkets being a rare thing at the start and now being everywhere, and the normal place to shop.

Think of “becoming mainstream”, “becoming normal” (or following a template applying to everywhere esle, like the other answer says, in the context of education. rather than dull.)

Except ...for police cars! Une voiture banalisée is... a trojan!

Comment: Il n'y a pas de différence de sens quand on parle de *voiture banalisée*, il s'agit d'une voiture qui ne trahit pas son utilisation par les forces de l'ordre, donc bien d'une voiture que l'on s'applique à rendre (ou faire paraître) *mainstream*, normale.

Comment: Yes : a car disguised so as to look normal.